# How do you write a gemspec for a gem that targets MacRuby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, macruby

I'm starting to write a gem for the MacRuby platform. What is the `platform` you're supposed to specify in the `Gem::Specification`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would use `universal-macruby`. YMMV